# CompletableFuture error handling in task chain

Tags: java, exception, completable-future

I completely lost it in how to do error handling with CompletableFutures. What I need is to have multiple tasks running async. These tasks consist of multiple steps like this example:

Receive data from DB -> Use this data for request -> Do another request -> Update DB record

Now every step could cause an Exception, i.e. DB record not found or incorrect data, request failed, bad response or update DB failed etc. I want to handle these Exceptions to log the error and stop the task and maybe even revert the task.

Now I build a new project to play with CompletableFutures to simulate this process. I used the following code:

```
public static Integer randomError() {
        Random rd = new Random();
        if(rd.nextBoolean()) {
            try {
                throw new Exception("RANDOM ERROR");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            return rd.nextInt();
        }
        return 0;
    }


ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(64);
        System.out.println("Main thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
        //Starting tasks
        List<CompletableFuture> listTasks = new ArrayList<CompletableFuture>();
        List<String> listErrors = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Starting threads...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int counter = i;
            //Add tasks to TaskQueue (taskList)
            listTasks.add(
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->{
                    //Simulate step 1
                    return 0;
                },ex).thenApplyAsync(x -> {
                    //Simulate step 2
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return x + 1;
                }, ex).thenApplyAsync(x -> {
                    //Simulate step 3 with a potential error
                    randomError();
                    return x + 1;
                }, ex).thenApplyAsync(x -> {
                    //On error this shouldnt be executed?
                    //Simulate tep 4
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return x + 1;
                }, ex).thenAcceptAsync( x -> {
                      //Simulate COMPLETION step 5 
//                    listTasks.remove(counter);
                }, ex).exceptionally(e -> {
                    listErrors.add("ERROR: " + counter);
                    System.out.println(e);
                    return null;
                })
            );
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
```

Now this piece of code creates 10 tasks, where every tasks consists of 5 steps. Now when Step 3 produces an Exception, step 4 still executes. Why? In my Serial monitor I see the error thrown but the CompletableFuture still completes OK. When I do `1 / 0;`. this produces an error which gets caught by `.exceptionally()`. How is that catched and not the custom thrown Exception?

What I want is on error, stop the chain and go do `.exceptionally()` to handle the error.

Comment: Because, of `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`. Your code never throws an exception. It does `return 0;` instead.

Comment: But it tries to Throw Exception, right? IntelliJ suggests to wrap this in a Try Catch block or add it as a signature which forces me to add a Try Catch block in the CompletableFuture step.

Comment: What do you think, will `try { … } catch (Exception e) { … }` do?

Comment: It tries to Throw the Exception and on error it catches the Exception. However this should not throw an exceptions, which makes me wonder why I have to use a Try Catch block to Throw an Exception.

Comment: Exactly “this should not throw an exception” and it doesn’t.

Comment: Then why does intellij force me to use a try catch block?

Comment: Because a method that does not declare to throw `Exception`, is not allowed to throw `Exception`. The try catch block ensures that the method does not throw `Exception`.

Comment: You mean in its signature? I thought this was correct indeed, but when I do that, it forces me to use a try catch in the CompletableFuture. This obviously has the same result. It prints the StackTrace on catch and thus .exceptionally() never executes.

Comment: It *does* throw. And then `catch`. And after catching, it does *not* throw. And yes, the lambda expression is not allowed to throw `Exception`, for the same reason. `thenApplyAsync` expects a `Function` and [its `apply` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#apply(T)) does not declare to throw `Exception`, hence, you are not allowed to throw `Exception` (or any [*checked* exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) in general).

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. So what would you suggest to handle exceptions in every step?

Comment: Don’t insert artificial checked exception. To handle those that you are forced to handle, e.g. the `InterruptedException`, you can rethrow them wrapped in *unchecked* exceptions. E.g. `catch (InterruptedException e) { throw new CompletionException(e); }`. Then, they should arrive at `exceptionally`.

Comment: Great! Why didn't I came up with this. Fixed it by throwing CompletionException as a wrapper for the Exception. Thank you very much!